# Schema Best Practice MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about best practices, let's suppose a month have multiple holidays, what's the best way to save this to mongodb? I has thinkin in a Json like this:

```
"2019": [
"JAN": [2,5,9]
]
```

but I would like to know our opinion

Thx, in advance

Comment: I would use an Array of **Date** objects

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data. In a document orientated database, you structure the data according to your (reading-)requirements, not according to traditional aspects like in relational databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a wrong way to do this, but I would do something like the following:

```
{
    "holidays": [
        "2019-01-02",
        "2019-01-05"
    ]
}
```

Of course, consider using valid formatted dates like pointed out in the comments, but hopefully you get the idea.

Best,